# Is it possible to provide password protection to my Android apps with the Google password? (OpenID for native apps)

Tags: android, openid

Use case:

1. User launches app
2. The user enters google password
3. The app lets the user to use the app if the google password entered was correct.

I don't want to provide yet an other password registering option to my users. I don't want to know my users' passwords either. It would be great if I could use the Google login(or other common login, like Facebook, etc...), just like it is possible to provide a Google login with OpenID for webapps.

Additionally: Is it possible on iOS?

Any ideas?

Comment: Dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330761/openid-for-android-apps-that-require-signin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Google Open ID for the same.