# It is possible to authenticate a Google user ( the one logged in on an android device ) to my server using the auth_token obtained form Google?

Tags: android

I have an Android app which let the users to add content to my server. Each user should have an account on this server.

The app communicate with the server through a simple API.

I want to use user's gmail address as the usermame and the auth_token obtained form  AccountManager as a password. 
 The problem is that the auth_token is not always the same so it cannot be used as a normal password.

Normally the server receive user's gmail address and the auth_token and it should check if the token is valid for received gmail address. The problem is that this is not possible: google do not have any method which will let me check this.

Do you know how can I let my users to log in on my server using their gmail address but without prompting them to enter a password?

I want to have something like "Login with Google" from Stackoverflow but I don't understand how can I make sure that the received token on my server is correct and not a fake one.

Thank you

Comment: Search for their OAuth 2.0 documentation and example code.

Comment: Found a solution: from android app I obtain the auth_token for contacts using AccountManager, send this auth_token with user'e email to my server and the server will try to get user's contacts using the received auth_token. If the call succeed, I will receive an xml which have a tag author: if the author == received user's email address, then the token is valid and I can authenticate the user on my server. Hope it will help someone sometime.

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu your final comment helped me a lot.

Comment: @UngureanuLiviu I love your idea. I'm going to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a way of sending the auth_token to google and retrieving information like the google user_ID since you can retrieve those infos :

```
{
  "audience":"8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "user_id":"123456789",
  "scope":"https://gdata.youtube.com",
  "expires_in":436
}
```

by making a POST from your android app on : https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg with the access token ... It's even indicated in https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Authentication The problem is that when you want to do it from your php server you'll have to send it in SSL because google requires it ... Here is my code :

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['authToken'])){        

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    $name = 'www.googleapis.com';//nom du site

    $data = "access_token='".$_POST['authToken']."' ";

    $envoi  = "POST /oauth2/v1/tokeninfo HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Host: ".$name."\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Connection: Close\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $envoi .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($data)."\r\n\r\n";
    $envoi .= $data."\r\n";      

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if($socket < 0){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_create() : " '.socket_strerror($socket).' "');
    }

    if (socket_connect($socket,gethostbyname($name),80) < 0){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_connect()');
    }


    if(($int = socket_write($socket, $envoi, strlen($envoi))) === false){
            die('FATAL ERROR: socket_write() failed, '.$int.' characters written');
    }

    $reception = '';
    while($buff = socket_read($socket, 2000)){
       $reception.=$buff;
    }
    echo $reception;

    socket_close($socket);  
}
?>
```

it just needs to be adapted to SSL and it should work to retrieve the google user_id ! After what you can compare it with the one in your database and the logg is done !

By the way, could you share your code with us (using your method with auth_token for contacts) ? or send it to fakeclark@live.com  THANKS ;-)