# Google OpenID web app and Android Java app

Tags: android, openid, google-openid

I have an authentication server whose web interface directs users to Google's auth page, which then sends them back to the authentication server to validate the OpenID key-value pairs. On success, the auth server checks its database to see if there are any existing users with the Google identifier retrieved from validating the OpenID key-value pairs (such as https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=moo). It is this identifier that allows me to match the Google account to a user record in my database.

Next, I'd like to build an Android app which connects to my server via TCP (not HTTP/HTTPS this time) and uses a Google account linked to the device (asking the user to choose, if more than one) to convince the server that the Google account they have authenticated to has the OpenID identifier https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=moo (or whatever it is).

How could this be achieved?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854781/it-is-possible-to-authenticate-a-google-user-the-one-logged-in-on-an-android-d?lq=1 (check out the comments!)