# Outsourcing android app login

Tags: android, python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, endpoint

I have been reading so much about using OAuth2.0 with google endpoint that my head is spinning. I have also read [OpenID for android apps that require SignIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330761/openid-for-android-apps-that-require-signin). Maybe I am going in circles; I don' know. So perhaps someone here can really help me out.

Usually, when I develop a backend, I roll out my own user authentication protocol. Something like:

- To register: user `POST` registration form to my backend; backend add user to `user_db`: email, username, password, etc.
- To login: user `POST` login form (username, password); backend returns token; user uses token to subsequently call to my backend api to access whatever; until user logout.

But I am now developing a backend specifically for a mobil app: android mobile app with app-engine backend built with python and google-endpoint annotations. So instead of having a typical `Login or Register` page, I want to outsource user login: I want the users to login to my app using their google account through `OAuth2.0`. So the new process would be like this:

- user downloads my app from Google Play
- user login using google OAuth2.0 (or my app does it automatically? -- preferred)
- with the token (?) obtained from `Google OAuth2.0` user is able to access my backend api to do whatever.

So naturally my question is: Will someone who has done this successfully please share their wisdom with some code? Also, please explain how my backend knows that a user is indeed authenticated. How about user logout, do I handle that? Again this is precisely an android app with an app-engine backend (that uses endpoint annotations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer part of your question with a fresh set of bullets:

The new process will be like this:

- User downloads app (accepting GET_ACCOUNTS and USE_CREDENTIALS permissions)
- User runs app first time (which activates it).
  (Your app now has permission to authenticate against the Google accounts on this device.)
- If user has multiple Google accounts, you can ask them which to use.
- You authenticate the selected Google account.
  (The code examples you need for this [are here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android#making-authenticated-calls).)
- Your server code receives the App Engine 'User' object as 1st parameter of Endpoint calls.

The link above also leads to the the tic-tac-toe example.  It's backend is in Java, but it should still be useful for you, particularly the Android stuff.  When my head is spinning from reading, it's time to start coding.

Comment: `When my head is spinning from reading, it's time to start coding` upvote for the quote :) . Thanks for the link, I will take a look at it.